# How to format While Loop when trying to define functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a continuous while loop until the condition reaches false, which I can't figure out when defining functions. I'm fairly new to Python.

I need to figure out a way to make the continue and break statements work.

```
import math

#imports math module to perform square roots

def main():

    while True:
    
        def GetInputs ():
            numA = int(input("What is coefficient A?"))
            numB = int(input("What is coefficient B?"))
            numC = int(input("What is coefficient C?"))
            #asks user for coefficients
            return numA, numB, numC

        def QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC):
         
        
            if numA == 0:
                    #if A is 0 program prints ""This is a line; not a Quadratic Equation.""
        
                print("This is a line; not a Quadratic Equation.")
                return -1
                askuser = str(input("Do you want to solve another equation? Type Y for yes and N for no:"))
                #asks user if they want to solve another equation
                
        
                if askuser == "Y" or askuser == "y":
                    main()
                    continue
                    #repeats loop
        
                elif askuser == "N" or askuser == "n":
                    print("Goodbye!")
                    break
                    #ends loop
                else:
                    print("Please type Y or N.")
                    break
                    #if the user doesn't type Y or N outputs "Please type Y or N."
  
            
            else:
                discriminant = numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))
                #calculates discriminant
        
                if discriminant < 0:
                    print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has no  solution.") 
                    break
                    #No solutions if discriminant is less than 0
            
                elif discriminant > 0:
                    numnegB = numB * -1
                    plussolution = numnegB + math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))) 
                    minussolution =  numnegB - math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC)))
                    finalsolutionA = plussolution / 2 * numA
                    finalsolutionB = minussolution / 2 * numA
                    print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has solutions " + str(finalsolutionA) + " and " + str(finalsolutionB) + ".")
                    break
                    #Calculates solutions if discriminant is more than 0
            
            
                elif discriminant == 0:
                    numnegB = numB * -1
                    zeroSolution = numnegB / (2 * numA)
                    print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has unique solution " + str(zeroSolution) + ".")
                    break
                    #Calculates solutions if discriminant is equal to 0
       
            
main()
```

An error message shows stating:  **Line 35: SyntaxError: 'continue' outside loop**

Comment: You DEFINE your functions outside of any loops.  You CALL them in the loop.

Comment: This defines functions again and again, ***forever***.

Comment: Also you cannot use break or continue for loop which is outside the given funtion

Comment: Why on earth are you defining functions inside a loop?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is indicating that the `continue` statement is placed outside of a loop, which is not allowed. The `continue` statement is used to jump to the next iteration of a loop, but in your case, it's inside the `QuadRoots` function, not inside any loop.

I understood that you want to give the user an option to solve another equation after one is solved.
I moved the `askuser` section outside of the `QuadRoots` function and place it directly in the `main` function to handle the "solve another equation" logic then removed the `continue` and `break` statements inside the `QuadRoots` function, as they are not needed there.

```py
import math

def main():

    while True:
    
        def GetInputs():
            numA = int(input("What is coefficient A?"))
            numB = int(input("What is coefficient B?"))
            numC = int(input("What is coefficient C?"))
            return numA, numB, numC

        def QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC):
            if numA == 0:
                print("This is a line; not a Quadratic Equation.")
                return -1
        
            else:
                discriminant = numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))
        
                if discriminant < 0:
                    print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has no solution.") 
            
                elif discriminant > 0:
                    numnegB = numB * -1
                    plussolution = numnegB + math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))) 
                    minussolution =  numnegB - math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC)))
                    finalsolutionA = plussolution / (2 * numA)  # Fix: Added parentheses for correct calculation
                    finalsolutionB = minussolution / (2 * numA)  # Fix: Added parentheses for correct calculation
                    print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has solutions " + str(finalsolutionA) + " and " + str(finalsolutionB) + ".")
            
                elif discriminant == 0:
                    numnegB = numB * -1
                    zeroSolution = numnegB / (2 * numA)
                    print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has unique solution " + str(zeroSolution) + ".")
            
        numA, numB, numC = GetInputs()
        QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC)

        askuser = str(input("Do you want to solve another equation? Type Y for yes and N for no:"))
        if askuser == "N" or askuser == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            break

main()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand I was trying to break the loop inside a function and outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Define your functions outside any loop, then call the function in the loop.  Here is the way to organize your code.  Note that QuadRoots has one function: ask for inputs, print results.  The rest of the login is handled by `main`, and that's where we decide whether to run again.

Note that `input` always returns a string.  There is never a need to write `str(input(...))`.

```
import math

#imports math module to perform square roots

def GetInputs ():
    numA = int(input("What is coefficient A?"))
    numB = int(input("What is coefficient B?"))
    numC = int(input("What is coefficient C?"))
    #asks user for coefficients
    return numA, numB, numC

def QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC):

    if numA == 0:
            #if A is 0 program prints ""This is a line; not a Quadratic Equation.""

        print("This is a line; not a Quadratic Equation.")

    else:
        discriminant = numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))
        #calculates discriminant

        if discriminant < 0:
            print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has no  solution.") 
            #No solutions if discriminant is less than 0
    
        elif discriminant > 0:
            numnegB = numB * -1
            plussolution = numnegB + math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))) 
            minussolution =  numnegB - math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC)))
            finalsolutionA = plussolution / 2 * numA
            finalsolutionB = minussolution / 2 * numA
            print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has solutions " + str(finalsolutionA) + " and " + str(finalsolutionB) + ".")
    
    
        elif discriminant == 0:
            numnegB = numB * -1
            zeroSolution = numnegB / (2 * numA)
            print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has unique solution " + str(zeroSolution) + ".")

    
def main():
    while True:
        inp = GetInputs()
        QuadRoots( *inp )

        askuser = input("Do you want to solve another equation? Type Y for yes and N for no:")
        #asks user if they want to solve another equation
        
        if askuser == "N" or askuser == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            break

main()
```